# Using minitoc in included chapters?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, include, minitoc

I'm writing a thesis. It is structured as a main `thesis.tex` document, that uses `\include` to include individual chapters written in separate documents. I would like to include a mini-toc at the beginning of each chapter. Minitoc works when I write `\minitoc` in the main `thesis.tex` document, but not when I write `\minitoc` in the individual included chapter documents.

For example, my main document contains:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{LatexFiles/ThesisClass/MMCCDPhil}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents  
\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\include{Chapters/introduction}
\include{Chapters/materials}
\include{Chapters/one}
\include{Chapters/two}
\include{Chapters/three}

\end{document}
```

and my individual chapters would contain:

```
\chapter{introduction}
\minitoc
\section{section one}
\section{section two}
```

In this case, no minitoc is printed in the document.

when I put it all in a single document:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{LatexFiles/ThesisClass/MMCCDPhil}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents  
\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{introduction}
\minitoc
\section{section one}
\section{section two}

\include{Chapters/materials}
\include{Chapters/one}
\include{Chapters/two}
\include{Chapters/three}

\end{document}
```

the minitoc prints out just fine for the introduction.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 4):

I should have set the mtc counter to correspond with the included chapters!
Adding:

```
\setcounter{mtc}{*corresponding previous section number*}
```

before the `\include{Chapters/introduction}`

fixed the problem!